# React Hoc function return class

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of `<Component />` from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const OOO = () => {

    //console.log(this.props.children)
    return class extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <Rem {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    }
}

class Rem extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Helo</p>
        )
    }
}

export default OOO;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This may happen if you return a Component instead of `<Component />` from render

That is exactly what you are doing here.  Calling `<OOO />` returns a `class` instead of a JSX element.

This isn't really a higher-order component because you are not taking the inner component `Rem` as an argument.  Did you intend to?  That would look something like this:

```
const withOOO = (InnerComponent) => {

    return class extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <InnerComponent {...this.props} />
            );
        }
    }
}

class Rem extends Component { ... }

export default withOOO(Rem);
```

If this is just a component that uses `Rem`, not an HOC, then you don't need to create a new class.

```
const OOO = (props) => {
  return <Rem {...props} />;
};

class Rem extends Component { ... }

export default OOO;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you used the function wrong, the function OOO returns a class and that class you can use. I have no idea why you would want to do this but here is how you can use the HOC:

```
//your code in a file called OOO.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
const OOO = () => {
  //you cannot log this.props here, it is not in the class
  //console.log(this.props.children)
  //I think you have to name the class but I'm not sure
  //Have not used classes in React for quite some time
  //even React documentation lists a large amount of
  //disadvantages using classes and it's only around for
  //legacy code
  return class MyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
      //here you can log this.props
      //console.log(this.props.children)
      return <Rem {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
};

class Rem extends Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Helo</p>;
  }
}

export default OOO;
//end of the OOO.js file

//here is how you can use it
import CreateComponent from 'OOO.js';
const Component = CreateComponent();
const MyComponent = ()=><Component />
export default MyComponent;
```